# Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Calculate $$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}$$

I use software to complete the  series is  $\frac{2}{27} \left(18+\sqrt{3} \pi \right)$

I have no idea about it.  :|

Comment: [This question deals with the related problem of evaluating the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k k!k!}{(2k+1)!}.$$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/how-to-sum-this-series-for-pi-2-directly/77626#77626)

Comment: In general, $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}n^2}=2\arcsin^2x.\quad$ Now differentiate both sides with regard to *x*, then multiply both with $2x$, then differentiate yet again, and, finally, let $x=\dfrac12$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider the function

$$f(x) = \frac{\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$f(x)$ has a Maclurin expansion as follows:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle (2 n+1) \binom{2 n}{n}} x^{2 n+1}$$

Differentiating, we get

$$f'(x) = \frac{x \, \arcsin{x}}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle \binom{2 n}{n}} x^{2 n}$$

Evaluate at $x=1/2$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\displaystyle \binom{2 n}{n}} = \frac{\frac12 \arcsin{\frac12}}{3 \sqrt{3}/8} + \frac{4}{3} = \frac{2\sqrt{3} \pi+36}{27}$$

**ADDENDUM**

There are many derivations here of the above result for the Maclurin series for $f(x)$; I refer you to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534736/evaluate-this-power-series/534756#534756).

Answer (score 12):

Recall the Euler Beta integral

$$\beta(a, b) = \int_0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} dx$$

and Euler's formula for it in terms of the Gamma function,

$$\beta(a, b)  = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.$$

In particular, since ${2n \choose n} = (2n!)/(n!)^2$, we have

$$\beta(n+1, n+1) = \frac{1}{(2n+1){2n \choose n}}.$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n \choose n} = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(2n+1) (x(1-x))^{n}} dx$$

and we have the series $\sum_{n\geq 0} (2n+1)y^n = (y+1)/(y-1)^2$. Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n \choose n} = \int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)+1}{(x(1-x)-1)^2} dx$$

and by routine integration (partial fractions or your favorite standard method), this [equals](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28x%281-x%29%2b1%29/%28x%281-x%29-1%29%5E2%20dx%20from%20x=0%20to%201) $\frac{2}{27}(18+\sqrt 3 \pi)$.

Comment: It's like the old days on MHF.

Comment: Some similar series which can be solved by using the Beta function approach
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/how-to-sum-this-series-for-pi-2-directly/77626#77626

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/224985/evaluate-the-sum-sum-k-0-infty-frac14k14k24k34k4/224988#224988

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75681/how-to-prove-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracn-1n-prod-limits-i-1na/75688#75688

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf) paper is very relevant to your question. In particular, $\bf Theorems \;\;3.4-5$ and $\bf Theorem \;\;3.7$