# Evaluating $\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} {2n \choose n-i}^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=i}^{\infty} {2n \choose n-i}^{-1}=\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{2n \choose n-i}}$ is a very interesting one. Here is what I have from WolframAlpha.

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n}^{-1}=\frac{2}{27}(18+\sqrt{3}\pi)$$

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {2n \choose n}^{-1}=\frac{1}{27}(9+2\sqrt{3}\pi)$$

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {2n \choose n-1}^{-1}=\frac{1}{27}(9+5\sqrt{3}\pi)$$

For $i \geq 2$, WA just comes up with closed forms involving generalised hypergeometric functions. Here is one [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28n-2%29%21%28n%2B2%29%21%2F%282n%29%21%20from%20n%3D2%20to%20n%3Dinfinity). I would conjecture that this is still in fact expressible in terms of the sort of form we see above but I have no clue about hypergeometric functions so I was hoping somebody could enlighten me. Also, it looks like some sort of computational artefact of not being able to start the sum at $n=1$. It seems to give a natural, consistent form for the first two cases ($i=0,1$), and when asking WA to sum it in the case $i=1$, but starting from $n=2$, it uses a hypergeometric function in the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28n-1%29%21%28n%2B1%29%21%2F%282n%29%21%20from%20n%3D2%20to%20n%3Dinfinity), whereas we know the answer should in fact be $\frac{1}{27}(-18+5\sqrt{3}\pi)$.

Also, could anybody come up with a (more elementary i.e. anything not involving special functions) proof of the formula
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {2n \choose n}^{-1}=\frac{1}{27}(9+2\sqrt{3}\pi)$?

I have struggled and failed, and this is the part I would most like answered if possible.

Thanks, and good luck (if needed).

Comment: The fact that you have $2\sqrt{3}\pi$ appearing in your sums tells me that the Gamma function is needed to evaluate these sums. I would guess that there is not a more elementary way to prove your equalities.

Comment: I can handle a Gamma I think if necessary

Comment: Are you not considering the Gamma function to be a special function?

Comment: Here is an "elementary" demonstration of the basic result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548563/calculate-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac12k-choose-k/548570#548570

Comment: @graydad the gamma is really pretty important and useful in higher mathematics. It is a special function, but at the same time the only one I'm not ruling out.

Comment: @RonGordon thank you very much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Generating Function for the Reciprocals of the Central Binomial Coefficients**

Using the fact that
$$
\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
=\frac{n}{n-\frac12}\frac{4^{n-1}}{\binom{2n-2}{n-1}}\tag{1}
$$
we can compute the generating function for the reciprocals of the central binomial coefficients:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k-\frac12}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(1)}\frac{\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(n+\frac12)}\\
&=n\,\mathrm{B}(n,\tfrac12)\\
&=n\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}t^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2n\int_0^1(1-t^2)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\frac{x^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\frac{nx}2\int_0^1\left(\frac{x(1-t^2)}4\right)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\frac{x}2\int_0^1\frac1{\left(1-\frac{x(1-t^2)}4\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{8x}{(4-x)^2}\int_0^1\frac1{\left(1+\frac{x}{4-x}t^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{8x^{1/2}}{(4-x)^{3/2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}}\frac1{\left(1+t^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{4x^{1/2}}{(4-x)^{3/2}}\left[\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\tan^{-1}(t)\right]_0^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}}\\
&=\frac{x}{4-x}+\frac4{4-x}\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\right)\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\frac4{4-x}\left[1+\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac4{4-x}\left[1+\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}2\right)\right]\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Plug in $x=1$ and we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\frac43\left[1+\sqrt{\frac13}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)\right]\\
&=\frac43+\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Extending the Previous Result**

Suppose we have
$$
F_k(x)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{x^{n-k}}{\binom{2n}{n-k}}\tag{4}
$$
$F_0(x)$ is given in $(2)$ above.

We can use the identity
$$
\binom{2n}{n-k-1}=\frac{n-k}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}\tag{5}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\binom{2n}{n-k-1}}-\frac1{\binom{2n}{n-k}}
&=\frac1{\frac{n-k}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}}-\frac1{\binom{2n}{n-k}}\\
&=\frac1{n-k}\left[\frac{n+k+1}{\binom{2n}{n-k}}-\frac{n-k}{\binom{2n}{n-k}}\right]\\
&=\frac{2k+1}{n-k}\frac1{\binom{2n}{n-k}}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(6)$ shows that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(xF_{k+1}(x)-F_k(x))=\frac{2k+1}{x}(F_k(x)-1)\tag{7}
$$
Formula $(7)$ gives us a way to compute $F_{k+1}$ from $F_k$, via integration.

---

**Example**

If we let $x=4\sin^2(\theta)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{F_0(x)-1}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\left[\frac1{4-x}+\frac4{4-x}\sqrt{\frac1{x(4-x)}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}2\right)\right]\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\left[\frac1{4\cos^2(\theta)}+\frac1{\cos^2(\theta)}\sqrt{\frac1{16\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}}\,\,\theta\right]8\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\[3pt]
&=2\int\left[\tan(\theta)+\theta\sec^2(\theta)\right]\mathrm{d}\theta\\[12pt]
&=2\theta\tan(\theta)-1\\[9pt]
&=2\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}2\right)-1\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
where the constant of integration was chosen because $xF_1(x)-F_0(x)=-1$ at $x=0$.

Thus, we get
$$
xF_1(x)-F_0(x)=2\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}2\right)-1\tag{9}
$$
Therefore,
$$
F_1(x)=\frac1{4-x}+\frac{12-2x}{4-x}\frac1{\sqrt{x(4-x)}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}2\right)\tag{10}
$$
Plug in $x=1$ and we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n-1}}=\frac13+\frac{5\pi}{9\sqrt3}\tag{11}
$$

Comment: I hope using the Beta and Gamma functions is okay. Since Jack D'Aurizio used them (explicitly and implicitly), I assumed it would be okay.

Comment: No I don't mind, thanks for the effort in fact. I just think that at this point in time it was a little unnecessary, given the answers. But thanks :)

Comment: I think that different approaches, no matter how many one already has, can be useful. The ideas used in each approach may be helpful in other problems.

Comment: well to me it's essentially the same approach. The tricks are just that, tricks. Still, you get the accept now :)

Comment: I believe they are basically different approaches. I am computing the generating function of $\binom{2n}{n-k}$ as a sequence in $n$ for $k=0,1,\dots$. We plug in $x=1$ to get the sums you are interested in. Robert Israel is computing the generating function of $\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty\binom{2n}{n-k}$ as a sequence in $k$. We look at the coefficients of $t^k$ to get the sums you are interested in.

Comment: (+1). Brilliant work. Is there a typo in equation five?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: indeed there was. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(2n+1)\frac{\Gamma(n+1)^2}{\Gamma(2n+2)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}(2n+1)(x(1-x))^n\,dx$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x(1-x)}{(1-x(1-x))^2}\,dx$$
and the integral can be easily evaluated through the residue theorem. Other cases are similar.

Comment: +1, when Gamma function was mentioned in the comments, I began waiting for your answer :)

Comment: I was just hovering over the accept button... it's a bit mean, but I think you need a couple more details.

Answer (score 4):

We can do an example to see how this calculation actually works.
Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{n\ge 4} {2n\choose n-4}^{-1}.$$

This is
$$\sum_{n\ge 4} \frac{(n-4)! \times (n+4)!}{(2n)!}
= \sum_{n\ge 4} 
\frac{\Gamma(n-3) \times \Gamma(n+5)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 4} (2n+1)
 \frac{\Gamma(n-3) \times \Gamma(n+5)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}
= \sum_{n\ge 4} (2n+1) \mathrm{B}(n+5, n-3).$$

Recall the beta function integral
$$\mathrm{B}(x,y)
= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} dt.$$

This gives for the sum the representation
$$\int_0^\infty \sum_{n\ge 4} (2n+1)
\frac{t^{n+4}}{(1+t)^{2n+2}} dt
= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^4}{(1+t)^2}
\sum_{n\ge 4} (2n+1)
\frac{t^{n}}{(1+t)^{2n}} dt
\\ = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^4}{(1+t)^2}
\times \frac{(9t^2+11t+9)t^4}{(1+t)^6(t^2+t+1)^2} dt
\\ = \int_0^\infty
\frac{(9t^2+11t+9)t^8}{(1+t)^8(t^2+t+1)^2} dt.$$

This integral can be evaluated by considering
$$f(z) = 
\log z \times \frac{(9z^2+11z+9)z^8}{(1+z)^8(z^2+z+1)^2}$$
evaluated on a keyhole contour with the slot on the positive real axis
and  the branch  cut of  the logarithm  also on  that  axis, traversed
counterclockwise.

There are four segments: $\Gamma_1$ just above the cut, $\Gamma_2$ the
large circle of  radius $R$, $\Gamma_3$ the segment  below the cut and
$\Gamma_4$ the small circle around the origin of radius $\epsilon$.

Using $$|\log(Me^{i\theta})| = |\log M + i\theta|
= \sqrt{(\log M)^2+\theta^2}$$
we obtain that the contribution along $\Gamma_2$ is 
$$2\pi R \times \log R / R^2 \to 0$$
as $R\to \infty,$ so it vanishes.

The contribution along $\Gamma_4$ is 
$$2\pi\epsilon \times |\log \epsilon| \times \epsilon^8 \to 0$$
as $\epsilon\to 0,$ so it vanishes as well.

We get  two contributions from  the logarithm below the  positive real
axis  along  $\Gamma_3$,  one  of  which cancels  the  integral  along
$\Gamma_1$ and the other one of which is
$$-2\pi i 
\int_0^\infty
\frac{(9t^2+11t+9)t^8}{(1+t)^8(t^2+t+1)^2} dt$$ 
i.e. the integral we are trying to calculate.

Let $\rho_0 = -1$ and 
$$\rho_{1,2} = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}.$$
We thus have that by the Cauchy Residue Theorem applied to the keyhole
contour
$$\int_0^\infty
\frac{(9t^2+11t+9)t^8}{(1+t)^8(t^2+t+1)^2} dt
= - (\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0} f(z)
+ \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_1} f(z) + \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_2} f(z)). $$

Now to  calculate these residues  we use a  CAS but it will  need some
assistance namely from the expansion about $\rho$
$$\log z= \log(\rho + z -\rho)
= \log\rho + \log (1 + (z-\rho)/\rho)
= \log\rho +
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{q+1}}{q} \frac{(z-\rho)^q}{\rho^q}.$$

We use this expansion to compute the residues, making sure that the 
constant term $\log\rho$ agrees with the chosen branch.

This gives for the first residue that
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0} f(z)
= \frac{57}{20} - 3\pi i$$
and for the second
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_1} f(z)
= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{23\pi \sqrt{3}}{27}
+ \pi i -\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}i$$
and for the third
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_2} f(z)
= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{46\pi \sqrt{3}}{27}
+ 2\pi i +\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}i.$$

Adding these and negating the result we finally have
$$\frac{23\pi\sqrt{3}}{27} -  \frac{211}{60}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The basic result is $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}n^2}=2\arcsin^2x.~$ By repeating the process of differentiation

and multiplication twice, and letting $x=\dfrac12,~$ you will obtain a closed form for your series.

Then, by using similar means, try deducing a general formula for each modified version of

this initial result, for $i>0$, namely, $i=1,2,3$, etc. If *WA* does not return nice results, use

`FullSimplify[...]`.

Comment: This is what I had first thought of when somebody mentioned this sereis. Using integration by parts. Worth mentioning, I think, although not all that elegant

Answer (score 2):

Using Maple, I also get
$$ \sum _{n=2}^{\infty }  {2\,n\choose n-2}  ^{-1}={\frac {
23}{6}}-{\frac {13\,\pi \,\sqrt {3}}{27}}
$$
$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }  {2\,n\choose n-3} ^{-1}=\dfrac34+{
\frac {2\,\pi \,\sqrt {3}}{27}}
$$
For $i=4$ Maple can't seem to simplify
$$\sum _{n=4}^{\infty }  {2\,n\choose n-4}  ^{-1}=
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,1,9;\,9/2,5;\,1/4)}
$$
but numerically it appears that the answer is $$- \dfrac{211}{60}+\dfrac{23 \pi \sqrt{3}}{27}$$
for $i=5$ it is 
$$ \dfrac{6169}{840}-\dfrac{31 \pi \sqrt{3}}{27}$$
and for $i=6$ it is
$$ {\frac {1709}{2520}}+{\frac {2\,\pi \,\sqrt {3}}{27}}$$
etc.  The coefficient of $\sqrt{3} \pi/27$ seems to have the generating function
$${\frac {6\,t-6}{ \left( {t}^{2}+t+1 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {-5\,t+8}{{t
}^{2}+t+1}}
$$

EDIT:
Ah!  Using Jack's method, the generating function for this sequence turns out to be

$$ \eqalign{
\sum_{i=0}^\infty t^i \sum_{n=i}^\infty {2n \choose n-i}^{-1} &= 
\sum_{i=0}^\infty t^i \sum_{n=i}^\infty \int_0^1 (n+i) t^{n-i} (1-t)^{n+i-1}\; dt\cr
=&\dfrac{\ln((1+\sqrt{t})/(1-\sqrt{t})) (t+1) t^{3/2}}{(t^2+t+1)^2}
- \dfrac{ \ln(1-t) (t^2 + 3 t + 1) t}{2(t^2+t+1)^2}\cr
& - \dfrac{(5 t^3 - 3 t^2 - 9 t - 2) \pi \sqrt{3}}{27 (t^2 + t + 1)^2}
 + \dfrac{1-t}{3 (t^2 + t + 1)} - \dfrac{1}{t-1} - 1 }$$

Comment: I used Maple's gfun package.  But for the full generating
function, I interchanged sums and integral.

Comment: Something seems wrong in that first term - won't $\ln(1+\sqrt{t}/1-\sqrt{t})$ have an even expansion in terms of $\sqrt{t}$ (and thus be expressible in terms of integral powers of $t$)?  That's a little problematic since it's being multiplied by $t^{3/2}$...

Comment: No, $\ln\left(\dfrac{1+s}{1-s}\right)$ is an odd function of $s$, so  $\ln((1+\sqrt{t})/(1-\sqrt{t})) t^{3/2}$ will have an expansion in positive integer powers of $t$.

Comment: Ahhh, of course - I should have been able to see that from the definition (it's of the form $f(s)-f(-s)$, so reverses sign when the sign of $s$ reverses), but somehow in actually trying to do the subtraction I got tangled. Mea culpa!

Comment: I think this is perhaps my favourite method, although getting a closed form from that for general $i$ seems hardly like an appealing job!