# Are these two series of the arctangent function the same?

Tags: power-series, inverse-function

I came across the series axpansion of the arctangent function shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835310):
$$
\tag{1}\arctan(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}\left(1+x^2\right)^{k+1}}.
$$
Is it possible to rearrangenge the equation above as the series expansion
$$
\tag{2}\arctan(x)=\frac{i}2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{(x+i)^n}-\frac{1}{(x-i)^n}\right)
$$
that was derived in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/appliedmath3020020)? In other words, can we derive equation (2) directly from equation (1)?

Comment: You should have $(2)$ sum over $k$ and $(2)$ can be split into logarithms using the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ if it helps