# Finite summation over reciprocal of binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

**Problem**: Simplify
$$ \sum_{m=0}^k a^m m! (n-m)!$$ 
where $a$ is real and positive, $k \in \mathbb N$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ with $k \leq n$.

Upper bounds and lower bounds may also be useful. One example I have found  is, assuming $a \neq 1$ and using $m! (n-m)! \leq n!$, 
$$ \sum_{m=0}^k a^m m!(n-m)! \leq n! \sum_{m=0}^k a^m = \frac{n! \left(1 - a^{k+1} \right)}{1-a},$$
but I am not satisfied with the accuracy of this bound.

I am aware of the somewhat related math.stackexchange.com question:  [Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548563/calculate-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac12k-choose-k)

Comment: That particular estimate is also valid if $a > 1$, just multiply both numerator and denominator by $-1$.

Comment: Using Euler Beta function one gets $\displaystyle (n+1)!\int\limits_0^1 (1-x)^{n-k}\frac{(ax)^{k+1}-(1-x)^{k+1}}{(a+1)x-1}dx$ for the sum. Maybe you can use this for a better approximation.

Answer (score 1):

One Idea is to estimate entropy function based on the value of $k$ (if you know the range of it)

$n \choose m $ $\approx 2^{nH(\frac{m}{n})}$

Now, if you know $k$ you can find a linear approximation to $H(x)$ in $[0,\frac{k}{n}]$ and use it to simply calculate the summation