# Peculiar Sum regarding the Reciprocal Binomial Coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Whilst playing around on Wolfram Alpha, I typed in the sum
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\binom{2x}{x}}=\frac{2}{27}(18+\pi\sqrt 3)$$
I'm not sure how to derive the answer. My first instinct was to expand the binomial coefficient to get
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x!^2}{(2x)!}$$
and then to try using a Taylor Series to get the answer. I thought that if I could find a function $f(n)$ with
$$f(n)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x!^2n^x}{(2x)!}$$
Then my sum would be equal to $f(1)$. How do I find such a function?

**EDIT:** I continued on this path and realized that I can use this to set up a recurrence relation for $f^{(x)}(0)$:

$$f^{(0)}(0)=1$$
$$f^{(x)}(0)=\frac{x^2}{2x(2x-1)}f^{(x-1)}(0)$$

However, I'm not sure how this helps me find $f(1)$...

Am I on the right track? Can somebody help me finish what I started, or point me towards a better method of calculating this sum?

Thanks!

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{2^{n+1} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Might help ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Hmm... I'm not sure how to use that...

Comment: Erratum: \begin{eqnarray*} \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{2^{\color{red}{2}n+1} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}  \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It's the Maclaurin series of $\left(\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right)' $ evaluated at $\frac{1}{2}$.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548570) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549028).

Comment: @RandomVariable ...yes, but unless I can just *magically recognize* any Maclaurin Series at the drop of a hat, I will need to find some other method of finding the answer. Can you tell me how I could *find that out* without just being able to see it?

Comment: It's not easily recognizable. But you seemed to want to know if it was related to a known Maclaurin series evaluated at some point. So I thought it was worth mentioning that.

Comment: @RandomVariable Okay. Thanks! Do you have any tips about how I might try to recognize a Maclaurin Series in disguise?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any great tips. But sometimes you might be able to recognize that a series can be evaluated by manipulating (differentiating, integrating, etc.) a Maclaurin series that you already know.

Comment: In general, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}~=~2\arcsin^2x.$$

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}=n\int_0^1 t^{n-1}(1-t)^ndt,\qquad n\ge1,
$$ giving
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}=1+\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty nt^{n-1}(1-t)^n\:dt=1+\int_0^1\frac{t-1}{\left(t^2-t+1\right)^2}dt=\frac{2}{27} \left(18+\sqrt{3} \pi \right)
$$ the latter integral is classically evaluated by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{n} ^{-1} = \frac{2n+1}{2^{2n+1}} \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx  
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute this for summand and inerchange the order of the integral and sum.
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} \frac{2n+1}{2^{2n+1}}  (1-x^2)^n dx  &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1}   \left(2\frac{(\frac{1-x^2}{4})}{(1-(\frac{1-x^2}{4}))^2}+ \frac{1}{1-(\frac{1-x^2}{4})} \right) dx \\
 = \int_{-1}^{1}   \frac{16}{(3+x^2)^2} dx - \int_{-1}^{1}   \frac{2}{(3+x^2)} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the standard integrals
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{(3+x^2)} dx =  \frac{ \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}} \\ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{(3+x^2)^2} dx = \frac{ 1}{12} + \frac{ \pi}{18 \sqrt{3}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
and the result follows.